# Accept digit decimal input in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

By far I have regex for JavaScript which simply does the following:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9][0-9]$)?$/i
```

1) Accept only 3 digit

2) Accept only 2 decimal

3) Accept only digit starting form 1-9 for starting

**But I would like to extend the regex to also reject the following input:**

1) No dot at the beginning --- .12

2) No dot at the end --- 1212.12.

3) No more than one dot --- 12.12.12.12

4) Not allowing keys of ("+", "-") in any of the input --- +12-12.21

In Summary the following of result:

1) 123.12 -- accept

2) 123.12.12 -- reject (more than one dot)

3) 123.12..12. -- reject (more than one dot & ends with dot)

4) +123.12-12 -- reject (starts with "+" and consist of "-")

**UPDATE**

I'm using a JavaScript framework and only required to code down object as the code base to dynamically create input components for me and I have forgotten about the input type for it is **'number'** rather than as a **'text'**.

```
      {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'Fabric Weight',
        placeholder: 'Fabric Weight (Value : 000.00)',
        name: 'FABRIC_WEIGHT',
        inputType: 'text', **<--- was 'number'**
        isShown: true,
        validations: [
          {
            name: 'pattern',
            validator: Validators.pattern(threeDigitTwoDecimalRegex),
            message:
              'Please enter number less than 1000 with / without two decimal!'
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: Your regex already meets the extra criteria.

Comment: https://regexr.com/ Try out this

Answer (score 0):

Try this (allow negative number):

```
/^(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/i
```

and (only positive number)

```
/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/i
```

https://regex101.com/r/Nm3t8d/1

|=========EDIT 1==========|

```
 /^([-\+]?[1-9]\d{2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$/i
```

1) Accept only 3 digit

2) Accept only 2 decimal

3) Accept only digit starting form 1-9 for starting

Demo :https://regex101.com/r/ocsUn4/3

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
^\d{1,3}$|^\d{1,3}.\d{1,2}$
```

See the example here --> [RegexTester](https://regex101.com/r/uTKcOo/5)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
------------------------
**`1 = false`**
**`12 = false`**
123 = true
**`1234 = false`**
**`123.1 = false`**
123.12 = true
**`123.123 = false`**

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('numberDecimal');
inp.addEventListener('keyup', function(){ 
  var regex = /^([1-9]\d{2}(?:\.\d{2})?)$/igm;
  console.log(regex.test(this.value)); //checking true/false
});
```

```html
<input type="number" name="number" id="numberDecimal" placeholder="Enter Number">
```